# Adding qty and add-to-cart in related products on product detail page for virtuemart 3 and display in linear fashion

Tags: php, joomla, e-commerce, joomla3.0, virtuemart

I would like to know how to add qty , add-to-cart button and display them in a linear fashion on the vm3 product details page.

I located a similar question here ([Display pricing and add to cart button in related products Virtuemart 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346328/display-pricing-and-add-to-cart-button-in-related-products-virtuemart-2-0)), but none of that works for vm3.

I think I found the right files at components/com_virtuemart/sublayouts/related.php but none of the syntax looks like it does in the question I found.

I will attach a before and after picture of what I'm trying to accomplish.
Before:

[image: before]

and this is what I would like for it to look like. After:

[image: after]

If you have any ideas or hints I would be so grateful.

This is what I've got in components/com_virtuemart/sublayouts/related.php:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

$related = $viewData['related'];
$customfield = $viewData['customfield'];
$thumb = $viewData['thumb'];

//juri::root() For whatever reason, we used this here, maybe it was for the mails
echo JHtml::link (JRoute::_ ('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=' . $related->virtuemart_product_id . '&virtuemart_category_id=' . $related->virtuemart_category_id), $thumb   . $related->product_name, array('title' => $related->product_name,'target'=>'_blank'));

if($customfield->wPrice){
    $currency = calculationHelper::getInstance()->_currencyDisplay;
    echo $currency->createPriceDiv ('salesPrice', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_SALESPRICE', $related->prices);
}
if($customfield->wDescr){
    echo '<p class="product_s_desc">'.$related->product_s_desc.'</p>';
}
```

This is what I have in components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default.php:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Show the product details page
 *
 * @package VirtueMart
 * @subpackage
 * @author Max Milbers, Eugen Stranz, Max Galt
 * @link http://www.virtuemart.net
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2004 - 2014 VirtueMart Team. All rights reserved.
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
 * VirtueMart is free software. This version may have been modified pursuant
 * to the GNU General Public License, and as distributed it includes or
 * is derivative of works licensed under the GNU General Public License or
 * other free or open source software licenses.
 * @version $Id: default.php 9058 2015-11-10 18:30:54Z Milbo $
 */
// Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

/* Let's see if we found the product */
if (empty($this->product)) {
    echo vmText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND');
    echo '<br /><br />  ' . $this->continue_link_html;
    return;
}

echo shopFunctionsF::renderVmSubLayout('askrecomjs',array('product'=>$this->product));

if(vRequest::getInt('print',false)){ ?>
    <body onload="javascript:print();">
<?php } ?>

<div class="productdetails-view productdetails">
    <?php
    // Product Navigation
    if (VmConfig::get('product_navigation', 1)) {
    ?>
        <div class="product-neighbours">
        <?php
        if (!empty($this->product->neighbours ['previous'][0])) {
            $prev_link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=' . $this->product->neighbours ['previous'][0] ['virtuemart_product_id'] . '&virtuemart_category_id=' . $this->product->virtuemart_category_id, FALSE);
            echo JHtml::_('link', $prev_link, $this->product->neighbours ['previous'][0]
            ['product_name'], array('rel'=>'prev', 'class' => 'previous-page','data-dynamic-update' => '1'));
        }
        if (!empty($this->product->neighbours ['next'][0])) {
            $next_link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=' . $this->product->neighbours ['next'][0] ['virtuemart_product_id'] . '&virtuemart_category_id=' . $this->product->virtuemart_category_id, FALSE);
            echo JHtml::_('link', $next_link, $this->product->neighbours ['next'][0] ['product_name'], array('rel'=>'next','class' => 'next-page','data-dynamic-update' => '1'));
        }
        ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    <?php } // Product Navigation END
    ?>

    <?php // Back To Category Button
    if ($this->product->virtuemart_category_id) {
        $catURL =  JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_category_id='.$this->product->virtuemart_category_id, FALSE);
        $categoryName = vmText::_($this->product->category_name) ;
    } else {
        $catURL =  JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart');
        $categoryName = vmText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_SHOP_HOME') ;
    }
    ?>
    <div class="back-to-category">
        <a href="<?php echo $catURL ?>" class="product-details" title="<?php echo $categoryName ?>"><?php echo vmText::sprintf('COM_VIRTUEMART_CATEGORY_BACK_TO',$categoryName) ?></a>
    </div>

    <?php // Product Title   ?>
    <h1 itemprop="name"><?php echo $this->product->product_name ?></h1>
    <?php // Product Title END   ?>

    <?php // afterDisplayTitle Event
    echo $this->product->event->afterDisplayTitle ?>

    <?php
    // Product Edit Link
    echo $this->edit_link;
    // Product Edit Link END
    ?>

    <?php
    // PDF - Print - Email Icon
    if (VmConfig::get('show_emailfriend') || VmConfig::get('show_printicon') || VmConfig::get('pdf_icon')) {
    ?>
        <div class="icons">
        <?php

        $link = 'index.php?tmpl=component&option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=' . $this->product->virtuemart_product_id;

        echo $this->linkIcon($link . '&format=pdf', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PDF', 'pdf_button', 'pdf_icon', false);
        //echo $this->linkIcon($link . '&print=1', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRINT', 'printButton', 'show_printicon');
        echo $this->linkIcon($link . '&print=1', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRINT', 'printButton', 'show_printicon',false,true,false,'class="printModal"');
        $MailLink = 'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&task=recommend&virtuemart_product_id=' . $this->product->virtuemart_product_id . '&virtuemart_category_id=' . $this->product->virtuemart_category_id . '&tmpl=component';
        echo $this->linkIcon($MailLink, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_EMAIL', 'emailButton', 'show_emailfriend', false,true,false,'class="recommened-to-friend"');
        ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    <?php } // PDF - Print - Email Icon END
    ?>

    <?php
    // Product Short Description
    if (!empty($this->product->product_s_desc)) {
    ?>
        <div class="product-short-description">
        <?php
        /** @todo Test if content plugins modify the product description */
        echo nl2br($this->product->product_s_desc);
        ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    } // Product Short Description END

    echo shopFunctionsF::renderVmSubLayout('customfields',array('product'=>$this->product,'position'=>'ontop'));
    ?>

    <div class="vm-product-container">
    <div class="vm-product-media-container">
<?php
echo $this->loadTemplate('images');
?>
    </div>

    <div class="vm-product-details-container">
        <div class="spacer-buy-area">

        <?php
        // TODO in Multi-Vendor not needed at the moment and just would lead to confusion
        /* $link = JRoute::_('index2.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=virtuemart&task=vendorinfo&virtuemart_vendor_id='.$this->product->virtuemart_vendor_id);
          $text = vmText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_VENDOR_FORM_INFO_LBL');
          echo '<span class="bold">'. vmText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_DETAILS_VENDOR_LBL'). '</span>'; ?><a class="modal" href="<?php echo $link ?>"><?php echo $text ?></a><br />
         */
        ?>

        <?php
        echo shopFunctionsF::renderVmSubLayout('rating',array('showRating'=>$this->showRating,'product'=>$this->product));

        if (is_array($this->productDisplayShipments)) {
            foreach ($this->productDisplayShipments as $productDisplayShipment) {
            echo $productDisplayShipment . '<br />';
            }
        }
        if (is_array($this->productDisplayPayments)) {
            foreach ($this->productDisplayPayments as $productDisplayPayment) {
            echo $productDisplayPayment . '<br />';
            }
        }

        //In case you are not happy using everywhere the same price display fromat, just create your own layout
        //in override /html/fields and use as first parameter the name of your file
        echo shopFunctionsF::renderVmSubLayout('prices',array('product'=>$this->product,'currency'=>$this->currency));
        ?> <div class="clear"></div><?php
        echo shopFunctionsF::renderVmSubLayout('addtocart',array('product'=>$this->product));

        echo shopFunctionsF::renderVmSubLayout('stockhandle',array('product'=>$this->product));

        // Ask a question about this product
        if (VmConfig::get('ask_question', 0) == 1) {
            $askquestion_url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&task=askquestion&virtuemart_product_id=' . $this->product->virtuemart_product_id . '&virtuemart_category_id=' . $this->product->virtuemart_category_id . '&tmpl=component', FALSE);
            ?>
            <div class="ask-a-question">
                <a class="ask-a-question" href="<?php echo $askquestion_url ?>" rel="nofollow" ><?php echo vmText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_ENQUIRY_LBL') ?></a>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

        <?php
        // Manufacturer of the Product
        if (VmConfig::get('show_manufacturers', 1) && !empty($this->product->virtuemart_manufacturer_id)) {
            echo $this->loadTemplate('manufacturer');
        }
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>


    </div>
<?php
    $count_images = count ($this->product->images);
    if ($count_images > 1) {
        echo $this->loadTemplate('images_additional');
    }

    // event onContentBeforeDisplay
    echo $this->product->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?>

    <?php
    //echo ($this->product->product_in_stock - $this->product->product_ordered);
    // Product Description
    if (!empty($this->product->product_desc)) {
        ?>
        <div class="product-description">
    <?php /** @todo Test if content plugins modify the product description */ ?>
        <span class="title"><?php echo vmText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_DESC_TITLE') ?></span>
    <?php echo $this->product->product_desc; ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    } // Product Description END

    echo shopFunctionsF::renderVmSubLayout('customfields',array('product'=>$this->product,'position'=>'normal'));

    // Product Packaging
    $product_packaging = '';
    if ($this->product->product_box) {
    ?>
        <div class="product-box">
        <?php
            echo vmText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_UNITS_IN_BOX') .$this->product->product_box;
        ?>
        </div>
    <?php } // Product Packaging END ?>

    <?php 
    echo shopFunctionsF::renderVmSubLayout('customfields',array('product'=>$this->product,'position'=>'onbot'));

  echo shopFunctionsF::renderVmSubLayout('customfields',array('product'=>$this->product,'position'=>'related_products','class'=> 'product-related-products','customTitle' => true ));

    echo shopFunctionsF::renderVmSubLayout('customfields',array('product'=>$this->product,'position'=>'related_categories','class'=> 'product-related-categories'));

    ?>

<?php // onContentAfterDisplay event
echo $this->product->event->afterDisplayContent;

echo $this->loadTemplate('reviews');

// Show child categories
if (VmConfig::get('showCategory', 1)) {
    echo $this->loadTemplate('showcategory');
}

$j = 'jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    Virtuemart.product(jQuery("form.product"));

    $("form.js-recalculate").each(function(){
        if ($(this).find(".product-fields").length && !$(this).find(".no-vm-bind").length) {
            var id= $(this).find(\'input[name="virtuemart_product_id[]"]\').val();
            Virtuemart.setproducttype($(this),id);

        }
    });
});';
//vmJsApi::addJScript('recalcReady',$j);

/** GALT
 * Notice for Template Developers!
 * Templates must set a Virtuemart.container variable as it takes part in
 * dynamic content update.
 * This variable points to a topmost element that holds other content.
 */
$j = "Virtuemart.container = jQuery('.productdetails-view');
Virtuemart.containerSelector = '.productdetails-view';";

vmJsApi::addJScript('ajaxContent',$j);

if(VmConfig::get ('jdynupdate', TRUE)){
    $j = "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    Virtuemart.stopVmLoading();
    var msg = '';
    jQuery('a[data-dynamic-update=\"1\"]').off('click', Virtuemart.startVmLoading).on('click', {msg:msg}, Virtuemart.startVmLoading);
    jQuery('[data-dynamic-update=\"1\"]').off('change', Virtuemart.startVmLoading).on('change', {msg:msg}, Virtuemart.startVmLoading);
});";

    vmJsApi::addJScript('vmPreloader',$j);
}

echo vmJsApi::writeJS();

if ($this->product->prices['salesPrice'] > 0) {
  echo shopFunctionsF::renderVmSubLayout('snippets',array('product'=>$this->product, 'currency'=>$this->currency, 'showRating'=>$this->showRating));
}

?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code you're working with.

Comment: I added a '?> xxxx <?php' at the end of the related.php file and the xxxx showed up underneath each product, so I'm pretty sure I've located the relevant  file.

Comment: Frank, have you managed to resolve this problem ?

Comment: negative. Do I get an award for the longest question ever to go unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using overrides and you have**

```
/templates/{your_template_folder}/html/com_virtuemart/sublayouts/addtocart.php
```

**than you can use it in specific php overrides, in you specific php override**

```
echo shopFunctionsF::renderVmSubLayout('addtocart',array('product'=>$this->product));
```

**On how to use sub layout** [here official documentation](https://docs.virtuemart.net/tutorials/templating-layouts/199-sublayouts.html)

**And also i think you need to read this one also** [CODE ADJUSTMENTS FOR VIRTUEMART 3](https://docs.virtuemart.net/tutorials/development/175-code-adjustments-for-virtuemart-3.html)